# SQL Query in Marketing Cloud to copy data from Synchronized DE to a regular DE

Tags: marketing-cloud

SQL Query needed to copy the data from synchronized DE to a new/regular DE in Marketing Cloud:

Marketing cloud and Sandbox have been connected. Contacts from Sandbox are synced with Marketing Cloud (coming in Synchrnized Data Extension). Now, I want to create a new Data Extension in Marketing Cloud copying all data from this Synchronized Data Extension and then automatically updating this new Data Extension using automation/Sql Query.

I have created the new Data Extensions with same fields as are there in the Synchronized Data Extension. Now I am trying to create an activity in automation studio which will contain the sql query (to copy the data from Synchronized DE to this new DE). I am not aware about the queries/sql, can someone please tell me the exact query for this?

[image](Kindly see the attachment)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify each column name. In your case, the ContactKey column should be stated in your query ..

Check out the help for more information about [SQL Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5);

Comment: Thanks Rachid. Issue is, there is a field in Synchronized DE with the name '_ContactKey' (starting with underscore) and when I create my own DE, I can't name a field starting with an underscore. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes this could be .. in that case, you have to write something like this select [_ContactKey] as ContactKey from synchDE

Comment: Thanks @SwatiMishra got the way around.